# Cannot run WDA ipa, dyld: Assertion failed: this->cputype == CPU_TYPE_ARM64

Tags: ios, iphone, webdriver, ipa, xcodebuild

I have made custom modifications to WebDriverAgentRunner and I'm trying to create a .ipa file to deploy it to my iOS devices.

The script I'm using to build the .ipa file is

```
xcodebuild \
    -project WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj \
    -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner \
    -sdk iphoneos \
    -configuration Release \
    -derivedDataPath ./out \
    -allowProvisioningUpdates \
    PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=${bundle_identifier}

mkdir -p ./out/ipa/Payload
cp -r ./out/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app ./out/ipa/Payload/
cd ./out/ipa

# Dump basic information about the verison of XCTest embedded in this ipa
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print Payload/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/version.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print Payload/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/Info.plist

zip -r ../WebDriverAgent-$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER.zip .
cd ../../
```

However, when I install it with [go-ios](https://github.com/danielpaulus/go-ios)
And run it with either `ios runwda` or `idevicedebug run com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner.xctrunner` I get the following error:

```
Assertion failed: (this->cputype == CPU_TYPE_ARM64 && this->cpusubtype == CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM64E && "chainedPointerFormat() called on non-chained binary"), function chainedPointerFormat, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/dyld/dyld-731.4/dyld3/MachOAnalyzer.cpp, line 3029.
dyld: Assertion failed: (this->cputype == CPU_TYPE_ARM64 && this->cpusubtype == CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM64E && "chainedPointerFormat() called on non-chained binary"), function chainedPointerFormat, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/dyld/dyld-731.4/dyld3/MachOAnalyzer.cpp, line 3029.
```

I have tried the xcodebuild command with **-arch arm64** and **-arch arm64e** and **-arch armv6** but nothing works.

How can I built the ipa file to be able to run it on any iphone device?